# Software Updater - How do I find out what the proposed patches actually do?

Tags: kernel, updates

My system: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

On Monday, October 19, Software Updater prompted me to install a bunch of kernel changes.
[image]
Normally I just let Software Updater do whatever it wants, but this sounded serious so I thought it would be a good opportunity to find out how the update process works by trying to find out why these patches were being pushed (e.g. Is there a known vulnerability that needs to be patched?).  I've spent a couple of hours searching ubuntu.com, askubuntu.com, about a dozen or so linux news sites, and four pages of search engines hits, ... and I've found no mention whatsoever of any patches being pushed in the last couple of days.  Now I'm wondering if my Software Updater is prompting me to install packages that no one else is using!

But perhaps a better question is:  where can I go on the web to verify that patches I'm being asked to install are official and necessary, ... and to find out what their purpose is?